# Display the current status of `expandtab` in statusline in macvim

Tags: vim, macvim, statusline, vim-airline

I am currently using vim-airline in my macvim and I want to display the status of `expandtab` whether it is set or not in the statusline.

I can find out the status of `expandtab` by running the following command `:set expandtab?`. From the vim-airline documentation I found that I can use something like this

`let g:airline_section_b = '%{getcwd()}'`

I modified it to

`let g:airline_section_b = '%{expandtab?}'`

but I am getting the error `undefined variable: expandtab`.

Can someone kindly tell how I can retrieve the status of `expandtab` and then show it in the status line. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:set` does **not** access variables, so you cannot use the question mark to query variables.

You are trying to access the variable `expandtab` variable, which doesn't exists. You actually want to access an option setting and those are accessed using the `&` prefix.

Sou you should add:

```
let g:airline_section_b = '%{&expandtab}'
```

Note, the quesion mark is not necessary and has no special meaning for VimL.

See `:h expr-option` for the details.

**Update**
This will only display `1` (expandtab set) or `0` (expandtab not set). What should work however is something like this:

```
let g:airline_section_b = '%{&expandtab?"et":"noet"}'
```

Which will display 'et' when expandtab is set or 'noet' when expandtab is not set. This uses the `<cond>?<true>:<false>` expression to display a certain string depening on the value of the <cond> condition. This is explained in the help below `:h expr1`

Comment: This works. But the only problem is that it display `0` or `1` instead of text `expandtab` or `noexpandtab`

Comment: Thanks it works. BTW did you mean you will update the *answer*?

Answer (score 1):

Vim options can be accessed live variables if prefixed with `&`. Example:

```
let g:airline_section_b = '%{&expandtab}'
```

See `:h :let-&` for more